# Resque Scheduler sending to queue but not processing

Tags: heroku, resque, resque-scheduler

I got resque and resque scheduler up and running on my development environment, but when I deploy to heroku it seems like the scheduler is not doing its job. It stays in delayed and never gets moved to the queue.

Here is my intializer resque.rb

```
if ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
    Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password, :thread_safe => true)
end

require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'

Resque::Server.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  password == "Mysecret"
end
```

Here is my resque.rake file

```
require "resque/tasks"
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do 
    ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
    require 'resque_scheduler'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

my video controller create action is doing this

```
def create
    @video = current_user.videos.build(video_params)
    if @video.save
      if @video.emailfans == true
        Resque.enqueue_at(10.seconds.from_now, NewvideoNotify, @video.id)
      end
      redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully Posted!'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

I am using a Procfile because it was recommended by heroku for resque.

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Answer (score 4):

wow stumbled across a fix for this.

altered my resque.rake file to this

```
require "resque/tasks"
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do 
    ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

task "resque:scheduler_setup" => :environment

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

I also added this to my profile

```
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

last thing i did was scaled up a dyno on my scheduler

```
heroku ps:scale scheduler=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the really little wonderful help. I have another question. Does your hook before_perform/before_enqueue works ?

Comment: how did you setup your procfile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537142/heroku-procfile-resque-puma-rails-5-resque-scheduler-setup